# early-signs-of-a-bad-sysadmin question deleted?

Tags: discussion, status-norepro

While i am browsing this question today i got notified with error as seen in below picture

[image]

i browsed this question from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/84685/early-signs-of-a-bad-sysadmin/84717#84717)

is the question deleted?any other place to verify the cache of this question?

Comment: What's your URL? The question is opening for me quite fine.

Comment: @Michael hampton shocked to see -3 votes even after status no repro tag is my question wrong?

Comment: Downvotes on meta merely indicate _disagreement_ with the question or answer. So I presume that the downvotes are because the problem is not occurring for the people who downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working now. Try viewing the question again.

Comment: at the time of posting my question it doesnt worked ,so i posted over here,thanks for correcting it

Answer (score 5):

This is popping up very frequently this evening.  It doesn't indicate that it's been administratively deleted; there is probably some kind of database issue going on.

Answer (score 3):

This is clearly an error message,

> We apologize for any inconvenience but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site
>
> It's not you, it's us. **this is our fault**